# How to structure data in Riak?

Tags: riak

I'm trying to figure out how to model data in [Riak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riak). Let's say you are building something like a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) with two features, news and products. You need to be able to store this information for multiple clients X and Y. How would you typically structure this?

1. One bucket per client and then two keys *news* and *products*. Store multiple objects under each key and then use map/reduce to order them.
2. Store both the news and the products in the same bucket, but with a new autogenerated key for each news item and product item. That is, one bucket for X and one for Y.
3. One bucket per client/feature combination, that is, the buckets would be *X-news*, *X-products*, *Y-news* and *Y-products*. Then use map/reduce on the whole bucket to return the results in order.

Which would be the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd create 2 buckets: news and products.
Then I'd prefix keys in each bucket with client names.
I'd probably also include dates in news keys for easy date ranging.

```
news/acme_2011-02-23_01
news/acme_2011-02-23_02
news/bigcorp_2011-02-21_01
```

And optionally prefix product names with category names

```
products/acme_blacksmithing_anvil
products/bigcorp_databases_oracle
```

Then in your map/reduce you could use [key filtering](http://wiki.basho.com/Key-Filters.html):

```
// BigCorp News items
{
  "inputs":{
     "bucket":"news",
     "key_filters":[["starts_with", "bigcorp"]]
  }
  // ... rest of mapreduce job
}

// Acme Blacksmithing items
{
  "inputs":{
     "bucket":"products",
     "key_filters":[["starts_with", "acme_blacksmithing"]]
  }
  // ... rest of mapreduce job
}

// News for all clients from Feb 12th to 19th
{
  "inputs":{
     "bucket":"news",
     "key_filters":[["tokenize", "_", 2],
                    ["between", "2011-02-12", "2011-02-19"]]
  }
  // ... rest of mapreduce job
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An even more efficient approach to this than using **key filtering** (as per Kev Burns's recommendation) is to use [Secondary Indexes](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/querying/Secondary-Indexes/) or [Riak Search](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/tutorials/querying/Riak-Search/), to model this scenario.

Take a look at my answers to [Which clustered NoSQL DB for a Message Storing purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286080/which-clustered-nosql-db-for-a-message-storing-purpose/13001495#13001495) and [Links in Riak: what can they do/not do, compared to graph databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752036/links-in-riak-what-can-they-do-not-do-compared-to-graph-databases/13001620#13001620) for a discussion of similar cases.

You have several decisions to make, depending on your use case. In all cases, you would start out with a **company** bucket, so that each company has a unique key.

1) Whether to store the items of interest in 2 separate buckets (**news** and **products**) or in one (something like **items_of_interest**) depends on your preference and ease of querying. If you're always going to be querying for both news and products for a company in a single query, you might as well store them in a single bucket. But I recommend using 2 separate ones, to keep easier track of them, especially if you'll have something like separate tabs or pages for "Company X - Products" and "Company X - News". And if you need to combine them into a single feed, you would make 2 queries (one for news and one for products), and combine them in the client code (by date or whatever).

2) If a news/product item can have *one and only one* company that it belongs to, create a secondary index on **company_key** for each item. That way, you can easily fetch all news or products for a company via a secondary index (2i) query for that company.

3) If there's a many-to-many relationship (if a news/product item can belong to several companies (perhaps the news item is about a joint venture for 2 separate companies)), then I recommend modeling the relationship *as a separate Riak object*. For example, you could create a **mentions** bucket, and for each company mentioned in a news story, you would insert a Mention object, with its own unique key, a secondary index for company_key, and the value would contain a type ('news' or 'product') and an item_key (news key or product key).
Extracting relationships to separate Riak objects like this allows you to do a lot of interesting things -- tag them arbitrarily using Riak Search, query them for subscription event notifications, etc.

Comment: This is a much better answer and is also up to date.